# Open non-whitelisted URLs in Cordova in ChildBrowser rather than main Webview

Tags: javascript, cordova, childbrowser

I'm trying to implement the official Twitter and Facebook share buttons in my Cordova/Phonegap app, and I'm running into major difficulties with them. Both of them attempt to load an `iframe` element to display their buttons, which works, but clicking either of them causes them to open in the Webview, with no way to open them instead in the ChildBrowser. This becomes an issue when the user is done sharing but can't go back to the app due to a lack of navigation buttons.

Is there some way to open a list of URLs in ChildBrowser by default instead of Webview?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the:

```
ChildBrowser.showWebPage();
```

command to open non-white listed URL's.

Coming in 2.3.0 we will [overload window.open()](https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser) in so that you can specify whether or not you want the url opened in the main web view, the OS browser or the special in app browser that does not have access to the Cordova API.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but the problem is that I can't find a way to manually open the share URL provided by Facebook and Twitter. It just shows up as link inside the iframe, which I don't think I can modify in any way.